# Three.js r70 Merging Planes together only renders the first plane?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Merging Planes together only renders the first plane, I'm trying to merge planes together to save performance cause I plan on rendering at least a minimum of 4096 at a time and I only want to have one draw call for them.

I'm using Three.js r70

```
mapGeo = new THREE.Geometry();
for (var y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        for (var z = 0; z < 1; z++) {
            plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1, 1));
            plane.position.y = y;
            plane.position.x = x;
            plane.position.z = z;
            mapGeo.merge(plane.geometry, plane.matrix);
        }

    }

}

map = new THREE.Mesh(mapGeo, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials))

scene.add(map);
```

[image: Image of the one plane rendering]

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!

You must update the matrix before merging Geometry

```
plane.updateMatrix();
mapGeo.merge(plane.geometry, plane.matrix);
```